# Cannot put a variable inside channels.get() on discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I've been trying to do some workaround on this thing but it just drives me crazy. The way I see it, it should work just fine but there is something going wrong with it... I hope I am not just really tired and missed a very easy mistake.

Anyway here is the thing. It's something pretty easy to do. an event is activated and then the algorithm below is supposed to read a certain database where I have the ids of the channels I want to send to stored, and it does one loop for each of those ids, outputting a different id on each loop,

(note: I am not doing it inside a client.on("message) event)

```
let channel = client.channels.get(dbresult)
channel.send(`test`);
```

This part was supposed to run 2 times with 2 separate numbers on the dbresult variable(since i have just 2 numbers on the database).

Now, when I run this part with just the id number alone and not the dbresult variable like this:

```
rows.forEach(function(row){
      //let dbresult = row.newsid.toString()
     let channel = client.channels.get(`0123456789`)
     channel.send(`test`);
   })
```

the script works just fine, but when I use the dbresult variable, it gives me this error

```
channel.send(`test`);
             ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined
```

Now these are the things I've tried:

- Putting a console.log(dbresult) just inside the foreach() block. It reads the ids just fine!
- Making dbresult a string (as you can see) and also I've tried not converting it into a string too
- Just Because I was desperate I even tried this: channel.send(`${dbresult}`), just in case.

Things that work:

- The things I want to get triggered outside this part of the script are just fine, the script always gets activated successfully.
- The script always reads each and every one of the ids of the channel. By removing the insides of "foreach" function and putting a console.log(dbresult), I saw that it outputs the different ids I want it to output.

Here is the whole script:

```
  let db = new sqlite.Database('./databases/Serverinfo', sqlite.OPEN_READWRITE | sqlite.OPEN_CREATE);
  const sql = 'SELECT newsid FROM news';
  db.all(sql, function(error,rows){
    if (rows.length <= 0){
      return;
    }
    if (error){
      throw error;
    }
    rows.forEach(function(row){
      let dbresult = row.newsid.toString()
      console.log(dbresult)
     let channel = client.channels.get(dbresult)
     channel.send(`test`);
   })
   db.close();
  })
```

Any help is appriciated of course

Comment: contact with discord support team

Comment: The error `Cannot read property 'send' of undefined` here means that `channel` is undefined. Which means `client.channels.get(dbresult)` returns undefined.

Comment: Have a look at the discord.js documentation.

Comment: @RingGamesCompany , I am pretty sure it's not about "looking at the discord.js documentation" cause the objects/methods etc are 100% correct (if you don't put the variable on the get() method that is.) also tried "fetch" and other methods without getting any good result. Also of course I did checked the documentation but found nothing regarding my problem, if you have anything more specific about it, share it with me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using discord.js v.12 you need to use the `cache` collection.

And yes, the id you want to use needs to be a string.

```
let channel = client.channels.cache.get(dbresult);
```

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ChannelManager

What you might consider doing is checking if the channel was found before you try to send something.

EDIT: The problem after updating comes from the fact that you store the channelID in your database as an INT which brings the following problem: `Numeric literals with absolute values equal to 2^53 or greater are too large to be represented accurately as integers`.

What that means is that it doesn't store the ID correctly because it is too large, we are talking in the Quadrillions here. This could happen either at your database or when you import the number into your code. Without knowing your DB setup I can't tell.

Example:

```
683328323304292410 // the actual ID of the channel

683328323304292400 // the INT that is stored
```

To fix this you have two options and both need to be implemented in your database.

- You can either convert the datatype for the row which stores the channelID to `bigINT` or convert it when you import the ID [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt)
- You can store the channelID as a string in the first place. (probably the easier solution)

Comment: Tried with cache, same error. I can assure you the ids it gets by reading the database are correct. As I said when I put the ids directly to the .get() method, it all works alright. here is a test i just did with console.log().--------> dbresult id is 324880501670281200
/root/bot/bot.js:48
     let channel = client.channels.cache.get(dbresult);
                                         ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Comment: That sounds like either your client is undefined or the `dbresult` is not a string. Can you do a `console.log(client.channels)` just before your `let channel = client.channels.get(dbresult)` to see what is actually there?

Comment: well, that's weird... I thought the result had to be "undefined" or something but console.log(client.channels) produces the actual map of the available textchannels (with ids etc.) but THEN I get the error "cannot read property "get" of undefined, as usual...

Comment: if you just added the `console.log` above the rest of your code that was to be expected. Can you check what version of discord.js you are using? Because your `console.log(client.channels)` should, in v.12 return something along the lines of `ChannelManager { cacheType: [Function: Collection], cache: Collection [Map] {...`

Comment: hmm seems like I could use an upgrade,i got the 11.6.4 one, i will upgrade and try again.

Comment: well you don't _need_ to update but it's always good to have the newest version.

Comment: Well I had a hope that maybe this was an actual bug of discord.js that got fixed on v12. Anyway, now i am working with v12, still same errors but yeah channel.id says "channelManager" now

Comment: Do you still get the `TypeError` or something else now?

Comment: channel.send(`test`);
             ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined. Yap very same one, I mean, it's really bugging me on how the algorithm works good when i put the id directly to the .get(method) instead of a variable, but when i put the variable, it's a different story. Even when i let the script run correctly (with the ids directly to the .get() method) when i put a console.log(dbresult) above it, it does the loops i want foreach() to do and it outputs the correct ids...

Comment: Yes the ID are correct but are they strings? That's the important bit. You get an error because your `get() ` doesn't return anything. That only really happens if the input is not a string.

Comment: I see your point, I once tried to put the id inside get() without the " " marks, it showed me the very same error. Thing is, besides doing a .tostring() function to the dbresult var, I can't find any other way to "Stringify" it properly to the method get()

Comment: This might not be the best option but you can use ``${dbresult} `` to make it a string. You need to put this inside thesequotation marks `.

Comment: nope, same error as usual... I am really out of options here XD

Comment: One last thing I can think of, try the `toString` inside the `.get()`. It should look like this `let channel = client.channels.cache.get(dbresult.toString())`

Comment: same error. I will give you the whole error message, maybe you can see something in it.      channel.send(`test`);
         

TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined
    at /root/bot/bot.js:48:14
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Statement.<anonymous> (/root/bot/bot.js:45:10)
    at Statement.replacement (/root/bot/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/trace.js:25:27)

Comment: if you just `console.log(dbresult)` without anything else if the `forEach` loop, does it give you all the IDs individually as a number or a string?

Comment: it gives the ids as a number (with yellow letters) and as a string (with white letters) when i use the "tostring()" function. Also, yeah, if I, let's say, try"console.log(dbresult)" instead of trying to send it to a channel, it outputs the ids I want it to output as expected.

Comment: You nailed it! That was the problem! And those were the only database cells I kept as "intergers". Daaaamn...